# how do you find the $x$ value for $-\sin x+\cos x=0$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, curves, transcendental-equations, stationary-point

> Find the sationary points of the curve and their nature for the equation $y=e^x\cos x$ for $0\le x\le\pi/2$.

I derived it and got $e^x(-\sin x+\cos x)=0$.

$e^x$ has no solution but I don't know how to find the $x$ such that $-\sin x+\cos x=0$

Comment: For what angles (in radians) is $ \ \sin x \ = \ \cos x \ $ ?

Comment: I dont know is there some angles I must memorize?

Comment: One of the things students are often expected to know from trigonometry in precalculus is the set of values of sine and cosine for the multiples of $ \ \pi / 6 $ and $ \ \pi / 4 $ . These are useful to know if you have to work much with the trigonometric functions.

Comment: @boojum what are these i am sudying A levels and was never told this could you please tell me what to search so I can memorize them

Comment: There is a table of this sort available in many places, but here's an example: https://physicscatalyst.com/article/trigonometric-table-from-0-to-360-cos-sin-cot-tan-sec-cosec/  (second table down) . If you learn the values for sine and cosine, you can use the definitions of the other trig functions to get the values for tangent, secant, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are asking for $0\le x \le \pi/2$ it's quite trivial that $x = \pi/4$ is the only solution of $\sin x = \cos x$

Edit:

Reasoning in $0\le x \le \pi/2$: notice that $\cos x = 0$ only if $x =\pi/2$ and for $x = \pi/2$ we have $\sin \pi/2 = 1 \ne 0 = \cos \pi /2$.

So we can say for sure that $x = \pi/2$ is not a solution of the equation $\sin x = \cos x$.

Divide by $\cos(x)$ both sides of  $\sin x = \cos x$ and you get $\tan x = 1$ which is satiesfied in $0\le x \le \pi/2$ only for $x = \pi/4$

Comment: how did you figure this out?

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: I understand thank you very much but how and where do you get the cousin to divide it with?

Comment: I did not take it somewhere. It's just a division that you can perform since you can avoid the points where  $\cos x = 0$ beacause in that case it's obvious that $\cos x \ne \sin x$

Comment: like where did you get the cosine from?

Comment: If you have an equation $a = ab$ for $a\ne0$ it's just natural to divide both sides by $a$ to get $b = 1$. Just practice and you will get familiar with this kind of things.

Comment: Thank you very much but do you know how to find its nature like if its maximum or minimum?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$-\sin x+\cos x=0$$
If and only if

$$\tan x=1$$

Can you get it from here?

Comment: Yesss thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can first simplyfy the equation to have;
$$\sin{x}=\cos{x}$$
$$\implies\sin^2{x}=\cos^2{x}.$$

Adding $\cos^2{x}$ to both sides gives;
$$\sin^2{x}+\cos^2{x}=\cos^2{x}+\cos^2{x}=2\cos^2{x}.$$

Note that $\sin^2{x}+\cos^2{x}=1,$ so we know that;
$$2\cos^2{x}=1$$
$$\implies\cos^2{x}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\implies\cos{x}=±\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.$$

Easily, the only solutions to this are $x=45^\circ, 135^\circ, 225^\circ,$ and $315.$ But since we also need $\sin{x}=\cos{x},$ the only solutions are $x=45^\circ$ and $225^\circ,$ or $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{4}.$ But since $0\leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{2},$ $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

For all $x$, $\cos(x+\pi/2)=-\sin(x)$ hence the equation is equivalent to
$$\cos(x)+\cos(x+\pi/2)=0$$

But we also have the identity

$$\cos p+\cos q=2\cos\frac{p+q}{2}\cos\frac{p-q}2$$

So your equation is also equivalent to

$$2\cos(x+\frac{\pi}4)\cos\frac{\pi}4=0$$

That is, $\cos(x+\frac\pi4)=0$.

But $\cos t=0$ iff $t=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$, $k\in\Bbb Z$. Therefore, your equation is also equivalent to

$$x=\frac\pi4+k\pi$$

And the only value of $x$ in $[0,\pi/2]$ occurs for $k=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Graphically we see immediately that $x=\frac {\pi}{4}$. But how about deriving this analytically?

Consider $\cos(2x)$ and use the formula for the double argument $\cos(2x) = \cos(x)^2 - \sin(x)^2$

Hence if $\sin(x) = \cos(x)$ we find that

$$\cos(2x)=0$$

Since $\cos(\alpha)$ vanishes if and only if the argument is of the form  $\alpha=\pi(\frac{1}{2}+k), k=0,\pm1,\pm 2, ...$ $ we have

$$x = \frac{\pi}{2}(\frac{1}{2}+k)|_{k\to 0}\to \frac{\pi}{4}$$

in the requested range.

We can also find the value of $a=\sin(x)=\cos(x)\gt0$: from the relation $\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2=1$ we get $2 a^2 = 1$ and hence $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.